# Passing to a MATLAB function arguments from an array and saving function results using FOR-loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I need to run a specific function 4 times, each time passing new arguments to it (getting 
them from array) and save the result in another array after each iteration.

Here is my function:

```
function VD (x,y,z)
(2*x*y*z)/1000
```

Here are my arrays with values:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]
z = [7,8,9]
```

Here is where I'm getting a mistake:

```
for i=1:4
result{i} = VD(x(i),y(i),z(i));
end
```

Mistake - ***Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.***

I'd like to have array *result* with 4 values, where each value is a result of VD function return.

Hope it's clear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid using the loop altogether:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]
z = [7,8,9]

result = 2 * x .* y .* z ./ 1000;
```

Comment: Without the '.', the '*' will perform a matrix multiplication. Try the following to see what I mean: A=rand(4); B=rand(4); A*B, A.*B

Answer (score 1):

Your function does not have a return value. It merely prints the results to the screen. Replacing your function definition with something like

```
function r = VD(x,y,z)
r = (2*x*y*z)/1000;
```

may help. However, there are much more efficient ways to do this particular task - see Gordon's answer on how to vectorize.